# Issue with Calling Stored Procedure on Babelfish Aurora PostgreSQL with SQL Server Compatibility

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, amazon-aurora, babelfish

### Issue with Calling Stored Procedure on Babelfish Aurora PostgreSQL with SQL Server Compatibility

#### Problem Description

I'm encountering an issue when trying to execute a stored procedure using a Babelfish Aurora PostgreSQL database with SQL Server compatibility. The stored procedure call works fine on a regular SQL Server connection, but it throws an exception on Babelfish. Specifically, the command is:

```sql
exec sp_sproc_columns @procedure_qualifier=DivDB, @procedure_owner=dbo, @procedure_name=spProcName, @ODBCVer=3, @fUsePattern=0
```

I'm using `mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8` and giving the below code from this library.

The error message I'm getting on Babelfish is:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: column "divdb" does not exist
> ...

More additional information:

```
2023-09-08 13:24:23.369 DEBUG 39492 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement  : SQLServerStatement:41 Executing (not server cursor) exec sp_sproc_columns @procedure_qualifier=DivDB, @procedure_owner=dbo, @procedure_name=spProcessPricesInBulk , @ODBCVer=3, @fUsePattern=0
2023-09-08 13:24:23.570 DEBUG 39492 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : *** SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: column "divdb" does not exist Msg 33557097, Level 16, State 1, column "divdb" does not exist
2023-09-08 13:24:23.571 DEBUG 39492 --- [   scheduling-1] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerException  : *** SQLException:SQLServerCallableStatement:40 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: column "divdb" does not exist com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: column "divdb" does not exist
```

And these

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: column "divdb" does not exist
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.findColumn(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:1360)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.setStructured(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:2183)
```

**SQL Server Query output:**

[image]

**BabelFish Connection Execution:**

[image]

This is the method in our code which is trying to set the TableType as proc Input.

```
private CallableStatementCreator getCollableStatementCreator(String procName, Map<String, ?> params,
                                                                 List<TableParam> tableParams) {

        CallableStatementCreator callStCreator = new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {

// procName = 'DivDb.dbo.procName'                

                CallableStatement stmnt = con.prepareCall("exec " + procName);
                SQLServerCallableStatement callableStatement = stmnt.unwrap(SQLServerCallableStatement.class);


                if (params != null) {
                    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                        callableStatement.setObject(key, params.get(key), DbUtils.determineParameterType(params.get(key)));
                    }
                }
                try {
                    for (TableParam tableParam : tableParams) {

                        callableStatement.setStructured(tableParam.getTvpName(), tableParam.getTvpType(),
                                DbUtils.getSqlServerDataTable(tableParam));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                return stmnt;
            }
        };
        return callStCreator;
    }
```

I deeper down and debugged the library code, especially `findColumn` method, that is throwing the exception. Here is the code

```
@Override
    public final void setStructured(String parameterName, String tvpName,
            SQLServerDataTable tvpDataTable) throws SQLServerException {
        tvpName = getTVPNameIfNull(findColumn(parameterName), tvpName);
........
        
    }
```

This is the whole code block that actually trying to find the column into internal database.

`SQLServerCallableStatement::findColumn` Method ( library `mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8`)

```
try (SQLServerStatement s = (SQLServerStatement) connection.createStatement()) {
                // Note we are concatenating the information from the passed in sql, not any arguments provided by the
                // user
                // if the user can execute the sql, any fragments of it is potentially executed via the meta data call
                // through injection
                // is not a security issue.

                ThreePartName threePartName = ThreePartName.parse(procedureName);
                StringBuilder metaQuery = new StringBuilder("exec sp_sproc_columns ");
                if (null != threePartName.getDatabasePart()) {
                    metaQuery.append("@procedure_qualifier=");
                    metaQuery.append(threePartName.getDatabasePart());
                    metaQuery.append(", ");
                }
                if (null != threePartName.getOwnerPart()) {
                    metaQuery.append("@procedure_owner=");
                    metaQuery.append(threePartName.getOwnerPart());
                    metaQuery.append(", ");
                }
                if (null != threePartName.getProcedurePart()) {
                    // we should always have a procedure name part
                    metaQuery.append("@procedure_name=");
                    metaQuery.append(threePartName.getProcedurePart());
                    metaQuery.append(" , @ODBCVer=3, @fUsePattern=0");
                } else {
                    // This should rarely happen, this will only happen if we can not find the stored procedure name
                    // invalidly formatted call syntax.
                    MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat(
                            SQLServerException.getErrString("R_parameterNotDefinedForProcedure"));
                    Object[] msgArgs = {columnName, ""};
                    SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(connection, this, form.format(msgArgs), SQLSTATE_07009,
                            false);
                }

                try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQueryInternal(metaQuery.toString())) {
                    parameterNames = new HashMap<>();
                    insensitiveParameterNames = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
                    int columnIndex = 0;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String p = rs.getString(4).trim();
                        parameterNames.put(p, columnIndex);
                        insensitiveParameterNames.put(p, columnIndex++);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(connection, this, e.toString(), null, false);
            }
```

This line, tries to execute the SQL query

```
try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQueryInternal(metaQuery.toString()))
```

In my opinion, the code line  `metaQuery.append(threePartName.getDatabasePart());` Should have been placed it wisely.

or the method  `ThreePartName threePartName = ThreePartName.parse(procedureName);`  should have been parsed it more accurately.

**By the way one more question,**

**In case I'm using Babelfish,** Do I need to use **PostgressDriver**? or SqlServer Driver is fine?

I'm using `Spring boot`, `Jdbc`, `Sql Server` `Java 8`

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:sqlserver://DB-URL;databaseName=DivDB;appName=XXXXX;allowMultiQueries=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=DivaDev*321
spring.datasource.sqlserver.schema=dbo

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.queryTimeout=300
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Comment: maybe you need to quote the parameters so they're real strings

Comment: @siggemannen - I did but this breaks further execution of the code.

 I suspect the driver should change these param implicitly as per db need.

Comment: I'm confused: if they are literals then you need to quote `exec sp_sproc_columns @procedure_qualifier='DivDB'` if they are parameters then you need `exec sp_sproc_columns @procedure_qualifier=@DivDB` why do you think what you have would work?

Comment: @Charlieface - Can understand the frustration on it. but if we leave coding part, and directly try to execute these lines on the SQL server client and Babelfish postgress then we will get the same error on Babelfishclient also, while same SQL runs fine on SQL Server connection. So it's more likely a level problem not code.
But what I'm trying to figureout how I can make the code compatible to it.
The above code is mentioned of mssal-jdbc-10.2.jar , so the code itself generating it in the same.
May be We need to think out of the box to run the code so it can migrate SQL server to postgress

Comment: Could be it would work as an ad-hoc batch (noted in the comments in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql#arguments) *If you pass a single word that does not begin with @ and that's not enclosed in quotation marks - for example, if you forget @ on a parameter name - the word is treated as an nvarchar string, in spite of the missing quotation marks.*) But pretty sure you are not supposed to do that, and not surprising it doesn't work in some situations.

Comment: can you see what the actual query executed on sql server level?

Comment: @siggemannen - The very first mentioned query in question, is the query that gets executed.

We can not add quotes otherwise it will break other executions. Also, this query is an internal validation query driver trying to validate if proc exists or not, and if it exists then how many params will be there. So we can not control this query.

Comment: "We can not add quotes otherwise it will break other executions" why would it do that? "this query is an internal validation query driver trying to validate if proc exists or not, and if it exists then how many params will be there" why aren't you using `sys.procedures` and `sys.parameters` then? Why would *executing* the procedure be the right way to do this?

Comment: @Charlieface - This query is being generated by the Driver class itself, I'm raising here because driver should have been added quotes.
If user will give inputs like `'DbName'.'dob'.'procName'` then the actual query is getting failed by saying `'DbName'` is not a valid column. 

In debugger, I provided quotes only on that code section that fails , the query gets worked but I again need to revert the procedureName to normal string. otherwise next code execution breaks.

it's like a switch, one fix will break another.
 .....see my next comment.....

Comment: @Charlieface - 
Also, in code, there is no way to add/update proc name string on `CallableStatement` class on the fly.

con.createStatement('exec procName'); this returns callable statement which doe not have proc change setter method, and procName is a final variable.

Comment: So what actual code are *you* running that makes this internal query happen?

Comment: @Charlieface let me update my question with additional method calling flow.

Comment: @Charlieface I have added the code, you can see the code after the second screenshot.

Comment: `con.prepareCall("exec " + procName);` should be just `con.prepareCall(procName);` I think. When you use an RPC call, you don't pass `EXEC` or the parameters in the text, just the name of the procedure, and the parameters get set on the statement object.

Comment: I will try that too, but this works with SQL Server, the issue we are facing is with Babelfish postgress. which has compatibility but with some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Unquoted string parameters are a feature of T-SQL but not currently supported by Babelfish (try `sp_helpdb master`). Currently such unquoted strings are parsed as identifiers by Babelfish, which is why you get the 'column does not exist' error. The same is true for unquoted parameter defaults in CREATE PROCEDURE/CREATE FUNCTION.
Support for such unquoted string parameters is currently being worked on. It will not be available in Babelfish v.3.3.0, but hopeful

Comment: Do we have any workaround for it? This is also happening in the case We are trying to call proc that have input params along with custom `DataType`  , in this case it throws, NOT ALL PARAMS HAVE NAME. 

My guess it's expecting the param type name for non-dtType params too which seems a bug.

Comment: Unquoted string parameters/defaults will be available in the upcoming v.3.4.0.
Until then, the only workaround is to quote the parameters.

Comment: any ETA for that release?

Comment: The best I can say is: "expected soon". The code for the fix is already in github of course.